# issue with material-icons : no picture icon on Apache Royale

Tags: google-material-icons, apache-royale

I want to use an icon image like in TourDeJewel, but when I use this code then the text "MENU" is showing instead of icon picture. (sdk 0.9.6)

```
    <j:IconButton >
        <j:icon>
            <js:FontIcon text="menu" material="true"/>
        </j:icon>
    </j:IconButton>
```

After check with browser inspector tool then `material-icons` css is missing

Could someone tell me why ?
Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the **CSS** linked automatically you need to use `MaterialIconType` class at least one time so compiler can process it.

The reason is that class has an `inject_html` directive in its constructor so when the compiler finds it includes it automatically.

In [Tour De Jewel](https://royale.apache.org/tourdejewel/) we use that class through binding:

```
<j:IconButton click="drawer.isOpen ? drawer.close() : drawer.open()">
    <j:icon>
        <js:FontIcon text="{MaterialIconType.MENU}" material="true"/>
    </j:icon>
</j:IconButton>
```

(Note in that file we use a binding bead at top level to make the binding work (i.e: `<js:ContainerDataBinding/>`).

If you don't want to use `MaterialIconType` you can link it manually using a custom  html template.